# VbNet imagelist listview position

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I've a listview connected to a image list.
I load 3 images, it's all ok.
Is it possibile to move images in listview and reassign index as viewed?

Now i've found a function to move items, but i don't know how to list images as moved.

Here's code

```
 Dim lvi As ListViewItem
    Private ListViewClass As New class_ListViewControl

    Private heldDownItem As ListViewItem
    Private heldDownPoint As Point
    Dim row, column As Integer


    Private Sub listView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListaFoto.MouseDown
        ListaFoto.AutoArrange = False
        heldDownItem = ListaFoto.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
        Dim item As ListViewItem = ListaFoto.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)

        If heldDownItem IsNot Nothing Then
            heldDownPoint = New Point(e.X - heldDownItem.Position.X, e.Y - heldDownItem.Position.Y)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub listView1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListaFoto.MouseMove
        If heldDownItem IsNot Nothing Then
            heldDownItem.Position = New Point(e.Location.X - heldDownPoint.X, e.Location.Y - heldDownPoint.Y)
            Dim item As ListViewItem = ListaFoto.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub listView1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListaFoto.MouseUp
        heldDownItem = Nothing
        ListaFoto.AutoArrange = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Each item in the `ImageList` has an index and, optionally, a key and you set the `ImageIndex` or `ImageKey` of each item in the `ListView` as required. If you want to change the image displayed for an item you change it's `ImageIndex` or `ImageKey`. What's the actual problem?

Comment: How can i change imageindex and reload it in listview?

Comment: It's a property. You change it like any other property.

Comment: How can i intercept newimage and oldimage index in those functions?

Comment: There is no "intercepting". The `ImageIndex` property is already set on the item. You need to set it to whatever you need it to be. I don't really know what that is because I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve because you haven't really explained it.

Comment: If i move image and get a foreach items listview returns always same index as beginning and not as i moved